# Word count Hadoop

Tags: java, word-count

I am working in a hadoop tutorial to count the numbers of words in a txt file.  The code is as follows:

```
package edu.stanford.cs246.wordcount;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
      int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);
      
      System.exit(res);
   }

   @Override
   public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
      
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job = new Job(getConf(), "WordCount");
      job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

      job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
      job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

      //reads byte offset as key and whole line as value
      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
      //writes <k, v> pair per line
      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
      
     
     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
      
      

      job.waitForCompletion(true);
      
      return 0;
   }
   
   public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
      private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();

      @Override
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                  for (String token: value.toString().split("\\s+")) {
                      word.set(token);
                      context.write(word, ONE);
                  }
      }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      @Override
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         int sum = 0;
         for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
         }
         context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
      }
   }
   
   
}
```

When I run the code I got the followings errors:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/home/cloudera/workspace/WordCount/output already exists
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/home/cloudera/workspace/WordCount/output already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
    at edu.stanford.cs246.wordcount.WordCount.run(WordCount.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at edu.stanford.cs246.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:25)
```

I really appreciate if someone can give me some advise to solve these errors. When I tried to change the number to  args[1]  and   args[2]  int following lines:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

Then I got less amount of errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at edu.stanford.cs246.wordcount.WordCount.run(WordCount.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at edu.stanford.cs246.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:25)
```

Answer (score 0):

I watched this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb5p8S5jZCc&t=429s

and then I realize that I needed to add more external JARs libraries.

I added all the libraries mentioned in the video and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).